# IPv6 eth0 ready kernel messages repeating every 5 minutes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipv6, arm

I have installed Ubuntu server 21.10 64bit on my Raspberry Pi 4 4GB. On this Raspberry Pi I am experiencing random crashes where i cant connect to my Raspberry Pi anymore (maybe unrelated). When I look into the kernel messages (dmesg -r) I see the same messages returning every 5 minutes.

```
...
[249091.255763] eth0: renamed from tmpc36f4
[249091.293783] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[249091.293956] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): lxc22c7742d2763: link becomes ready
[249391.153844] eth0: renamed from tmpd8d60
[249391.174580] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[249391.174728] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): lxc550774b3dde9: link becomes ready
[249691.143024] eth0: renamed from tmp8f13e
[249691.162612] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[249691.162734] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): lxc8c4908ef491c: link becomes ready
```

Currently I don't know if this can cause any harm and want to find the cause of this. Anyone knows whats causing this and how to fix or how I can troubleshoot this?

Edit:
Output of `ip monitor link`

```
1781: tmpb665a@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 46:ac:aa:96:3d:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
1782: lxcdabfd2241823@tmpb665a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 2e:5c:07:51:5d:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
1782: lxcdabfd2241823@tmpb665a: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN group default 
    link/ether 2e:5c:07:51:5d:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted 1781: tmpb665a@lxcdabfd2241823: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 46:ac:aa:96:3d:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff new-netnsid 1 new-ifindex 1781
1782: lxcdabfd2241823@if1781: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 2e:5c:07:51:5d:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
1782: lxcdabfd2241823@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 2e:5c:07:51:5d:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted 1782: lxcdabfd2241823@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 2e:5c:07:51:5d:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Output of `udevadm monitor --kernel`

```
KERNEL[265289.275809] add      /devices/virtual/net/tmp650b2 (net)
KERNEL[265289.275952] add      /devices/virtual/net/tmp650b2/queues/rx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[265289.276071] add      /devices/virtual/net/tmp650b2/queues/tx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[265289.276687] add      /devices/virtual/net/lxc2eea12d7a087 (net)
KERNEL[265289.276904] add      /devices/virtual/net/lxc2eea12d7a087/queues/rx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[265289.277001] add      /devices/virtual/net/lxc2eea12d7a087/queues/tx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[265289.312440] remove   /devices/virtual/net/tmp650b2 (net)
KERNEL[265292.025539] remove   /devices/virtual/net/lxc2eea12d7a087/queues/rx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[265292.027185] remove   /devices/virtual/net/lxc2eea12d7a087/queues/tx-0 (queues)
KERNEL[265292.028565] remove   /devices/virtual/net/lxc2eea12d7a087 (net)
```

Comment: Do you have more messages in between these? What do you get out of `ip monitor link` and `udevadm monitor --kernel`?

Comment: I have added the outputs of the commands

Comment: Looks like the interface being created/deleted is virtual, not physical (despite being named eth0) – can you check the system logs as well (through `journalctl -f` or `tail -f /var/log/syslog`)?

Comment: Ah, in the logs i found the root cause, and also more error logs. Will look into these messages, Thanks for the help already!